# Unauthorized Session, not found, is the BigBlueButton frontend is server from localhost

Tags: bigbluebutton

## the following architecture is working Working Use Case:

- FrontEnd: React (web.example.com)
- Server: Node.js (server.example.com)
- BBB Server (bbb.example.com)

Note: The BBB is loaded in an iframe in frontend/react/web.example.com

Eg.
URL_TO_JOIN = is the url received from BBB after a meeeting is created via an API call

```
<iframe
  allow="microphone; camera"
  src={URL_TO_JOIN}
  allowfullscreen={true}
>
</iframe>
```

## Not Working Use Case:

- if the FrontEnd is served in local environment React (web.example.local)
- https is also setup

/etc/host

```
127.0.0.1 web.example.local
```

nginx serve the frontend/react/web.example.local traffic with `https`

Error message:

```
Unauthorized Session
not found
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

I've created a subdomain `web.local.example.com` and hosted the frontend/react/web.localhost.example.com using Nginx as load balancer with ssl

Note:
web.local.example solves the requirement of same-origin, hence resolves the issue